# Hide and Show Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin, uinavigationbar

How to hide NavigationBarHidden  for LoginViewController and show for DashBoardViewController

```
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    navigationController = new UINavigationController();

    loginViewController = new LoginViewController ();
    navigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true,true);
    navigationController.AddChildViewController (loginViewController);

    if (validAuth == "AuthenticationValidUser" ){

        var dashBoardViewController = new DashBoardViewController ();
        navigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (false,true);
        navigationController.AddChildViewController (dashBoardViewController);
    }

window.RootViewController = navigationController;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
return true;
```

Please advice me proper way.

@All 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access NavigationController property in your concrete View Controller, for example in ViewWillAppear and set it there. For example:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

    //hide
    NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
    //show
    //NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
}
```

Comment: The same thing i am calling in ViewDidLoad my application crash...!!! Now and calling in ViewWillAppear its works fine... for me Thanks you !!